# DLL load and call class method

Tags: visual-c++, dll

To load a DLL and call function in VC++, we use    LoadLibrary    and     GetProcAddress   , which needs mangled name of the method. Does it instantiate a class object and then call the method?

If it does not then how can I call a method in a class but instantiating an object of the class and then call a method?

What is process to load .h file, load class, instantiate object and then call a method in VC++

Comment: C++ methods under the hood are just functions with first `this` parameter.

Comment: I am trying to write a code that will ask for name of DLL file on runtime and name of function to be execute. So i need to instanciate a class runtime and create object and using that need to call that function.

Is that possible?

Comment: Note: I'm not very familiar to C++ internals, so these are only my thoughts. I think that yes, you can do that, but since C++ has no standardised ABI, each compiler may (and it does) position class methods and fields at different offsets. Within a specific compiler version this could work, if you had the class definition.

Comment: Any pointer to it using code snippet? That will really help.

Comment: @Joulukuusi - re your first comment, C++ constructors don't have a `this` parameter because there *is* no `this` until after construction.

Comment: @RogerRowland In a way, they do. They need to know where the new object is located.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes - ok, I agree, even if it's splitting hairs ;-) The article I linked to in my answer is actually very informative on that subject too. Would appreciate your view on the technicalities.

Answer (score 4):

There is actually a [very good example on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9405/Using-classes-exported-from-a-DLL-using-LoadLibrar) that describes exactly how to do this.

**EDIT** with reference to your comment, if you read the above article, you'll see that `GetProcAddress()` does nothing more than return a function pointer. If you want to create an instance of a `class` that's exported from the DLL, you have to allocate memory and force the system to invoke the constructor of the class to instantiate it there. Once that's done, however, I'm sort of assuming that you can call functions defined in the class in the normal way by using the object you just created.

Comment: Hi but again I have a very basic question. Suppose DLL A.dll has exported,

`Class A{
  public function B(){//some code}
}`

Does LoadLibrary, GetProcAddress instanciates `Class A` and create object A and then function pointer returned for `object A.B()`?

Comment: Edited answer to address your comment - see above.

Comment: Nice, but unfortunately MSVC's `__asm` only works for x86 and does not support the `asm` keyword. +1 anyway for the interesting read.