# how to use unmanaged .dll, .lib, .exp in c++ project

Tags: c++, .net, dll, mono, native

I am way out of my league here so I am hoping someone can give me some advice on how to proceed.

The long story is, I started with a jar which i ran an application called ikvm on to produce a .net library of my java classes. This was tested and works fine. So then I had a .net dll, which i used [mono](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/aot/) aot to generate an unmanaged .dll, .exp, and .lib but no header file. I do know the class names and methods involved.

Now what I can't figure out is how I use these files to work with these classes in a c++ project without the header file. I am using visual studio. If there is any information I missed that would be helpful please comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have got an unmanged DLL then there are many way to use it c++.

One easy way could be to use LoadLibrary() & GetProcAddress() function. For example:

```
//Define the function prototype
typedef int (CALLBACK* FirstFunction)(LPCTSTR);

void main()
{
   HINSTANCE dllHandle = NULL;              
   FirstFunction pFirstFunction = NULL;

   //Load DLL
    dllHandle = LoadLibrary("Your.dll");

   if(dllHandle != NULL)
   {
      //Get pointer to function FindBook
      pFirstFunction = (FirstFunction)GetProcAddress(dllHandle,
         "FindBook");

      // If function pointer is valid then you can use it 
      if (pFirstFunction != NULL)
      {
         LPCTSTR strBook = "Duchamp";
         short nSuccessCode = pFirstFunction(strBook);
      }

   }

}
```

Comment: I think i understand a good part of that, but my greenness is still lurking. Say I have a class called "MyClass" its constructor does all of its setup automagically, then i just have to call a method to get the result which is another class (MyClass2) in my dll. In managed .net this looked like:            
    MyClass2 MyClass2Instance = (MyClass2) MyClassInstance.MyClassMethod(string str); How would i go about setting that up?

Comment: Also When i was reading, it looked like I needed to add a linker reference or something to my .lib?

Comment: LoadLibrary doesnt need linking of .lib. You can use like Depends or DUMPBIN to find exported contents of your DLL. I'm still not sure that you have got a unmanaged dll.

Comment: Okay, that explains that. It definitely is an unmanaged dll. Used mono --aot=full to compile it. It actually will only run on x86, x86_64 ELF. I think i'm getting what you said tho, along with following another video I found. I get the function part, but how do I go about getting a class?

Comment: Ahah, I found another thread that will answer this question. Thank you for your answer, it showed me what to look for and explained a step I wasn't getting! [Here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9405/Using-classes-exported-from-a-DLL-using-LoadLibrar) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16011945/dll-load-and-call-class-method)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a header file, you either need to "manufacture" one (according to the exact specifications in the .dll), or load the library and functions dynamically - see [LoadLibrary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175(v=vs.85).aspx) and [GetProcAddress](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212(v=vs.85).aspx).

To see the exact function specifications in the dll, you can use e.g. [DependencyWalker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) (external tool) or directly the dumpbin utility provided by the Visual Studio:

```
dumpbin /exports thename.dll
```

This will show all the exports to begin with.

In particular, be careful about the calling convention (stdcall, fastcall, etc.).